# The map $\mathbb{Z}[S] \rightarrow \lim_i \mathbb{Z}[S_i]$ is injective

Tags: ct.category-theory, condensed-mathematics

In the proof of proposition 2.1. of [Analytic.pdf](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf) there is the following map: Let $S = \lim_i S_i$ a profinite set. Let $p_i: S \rightarrow S_i$ be the projection. We can define the following map using the universal property of the limit and of the free abelian group:
\begin{align*}
\iota_T: \mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{Cont}(T,S)] &\longrightarrow \lim_i \underline{\mathbb{Z}[S_i]}(T) =\lim_i \mathrm{Cont}(T,\mathbb{Z}[S_i]) \\
\sum_{k \leq N} n_k [f_k] &\longmapsto \left( t \mapsto \sum_{k \leq N} n_k [p_i(f_k(t))] \right)_i    
\end{align*}
In the proof professors Scholze and Clausen claim that the first step is to check that this map is injective for $T = *$ a point, but I could not prove it. What I managed to do is to show that for $N = 1,2,3,4,5$ if $\sum_{k \leq N} n_k [f_k]$ is in the kernel, then $n_k = 0$. But with my method is necessary to separate in a lot of cases and for arbitrary $N$ it gets messy.

How to prove that $\iota_*$ is injective?

Comment: Take a nonzero element $\sum_{k\leq N} n_k [f_k]$; you can assume that all $f_k\in S$ are different and all $n_k\neq 0$. Take a quotient $S\to S_i$ such that the $p_i(f_k)\in S_i$ are still different. Then the image of this element in $\mathbb Z[S_i]$ is still nonzero.

Comment: @PeterScholze Thanks for the answer! Do you mean that exist $i$ such that $p_i(f_0)$, ..., $p_i(f_N)$ are all different? But what if $S = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{0,1\}$ with $S_i = \{0, 1 \}$ and we take $f_k = (0,0,0,...,0,1,0,...)$ with $1$ in the $k$th coordinate?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/417444/82179) is closely related (and my answer there contains some more details). To answer the question from your comment: the term "inverse limit" usually means "limit over a [small] cofiltered index category". For each pair $i \neq j$ there exists an index $a_{i,j}$ such that $p_{a_{i,j}}(f_i) \neq p_{a_{i,j}}(f_j) \in S_{a_{i,j}}$, and since the index category is cofiltered there exists an index $a$ mapping to all $a_{i,j}$, so that $p_a(f_i) \neq p_a(f_j) \in S_a$ for all $i \neq j$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thank you very much!